# Connecting image from imgArray to select

Tags: arrays, function, select

I'm building a little Js project in which you can select 2 types of motorcycles, and 3 types of weather, and based on you're choices you will get street and snow tires. But right now im trying to connect an image to the option with an imgArray, but can't figure out how to do it. Right now im using onchange in html, I have to do it with eventlisterner but I didn't get that to work. Here's my code

HTML:

```
<select id="motor" onchange="selectBike()">
    <option value="Allroad">Allroad</option>
    <option value="Street">Street</option>
</select>
```

Js

```
var imgArray2 = ['KTM790', "KTM790D"];

document.querySelector("img").src = 'Bike/' + imgArray2

function selectBike() {
    var x = document.getElementById('motor').value;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "you selected " + x;
}

function selectWeather() {
    var c = document.getElementById('weather').value;

    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "it's " + c;
}
```

Comment: you need to set the image src or get the chosen i mage ?

Comment: In the html you mean?

Comment: I don't get what you want to do ?

get the user selected image and add it to array ?
or when the user choose a value display an image

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. for example you select value="Allroad. and when you select allroad i want an image from the array to show in the html, in this case KTM790.

Answer (score 0):

You need yo have an `imgObjects` which has the values and the images name 
then you can use that code which will create image element and add it

```js
var imgObjects =  {
Allroad : "KTM790D",
Street : "KTM790"
}

function selectBike() {
    var x = document.getElementById('motor').value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "you selected " + x;
  var imgElm =   document.createElement("img");
  imgElm.src = window.location.hostname + "/Bikes/" + imgObjects[x]+".jpg";
console.log(imgElm)
      document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(imgElm);  
}
```

```html
<select id="motor" onchange="selectBike()">
    <option value="Allroad">Allroad</option>
    <option value="Street">Street</option>
</select>


<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, You can create a JSON object and store image data into the Array object. When you adding image data, you should convert image to the base64 format. [here is the link](https://www.base64-image.de). Here is my solution

---

```
<html>
    <head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<body>

    <select id="bikes" onchange="selBike()">
        <option >Allroad</option>
        <option >Street</option>
    </select>

    <div id="demo"></div>
    <div id="demo1"></div>

    <script>


    var imgBikes = [{"imgURL" : "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFRAWIB0iIiAdHx8kKDQsJCYxJx8fLT0tMTU3Ojo6Iys/RD84QzQ5OjcBCgoKDQwNGg8PGjclHyU3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3N//AABEIAGAAYAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAEAAQUBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAMEBQYHAQL/xAA7EAABAwMCAwMICAYDAAAAAAABAAIDBAURBhITITEHQVEUIlRhcXSUshYXMzVikbHRI1JVcoGhFTI0/8QAFAEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/EABQRAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AO4oiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICLxzgxpc4gNAySTyAWN+kNk/rFu+KZ+6ClqvUFJpiyT3Sta97I8NZHGPOkeeQaP3WjR2XWerqKlv8AS6xNtZWxNljoYIHBkLTzA3B3nHxJHP2cl8dt90t9bo+GKiuFLO8V0biyGZrjja/uB9iz3ZzfbTFoeyQ1F0oopo6RjHxvqGNc0jlzBPJBhm1+oezqWkn1bfWXi01tQKdz+GWyUrtrjv8AxNw05GfWPA9NY9sjGvY4Oa4ZBByCFyLt6ulFW6ftkNFWU9Q7y3e7gytfgCN47j+JdC01dKH6O2sSV1MHijh3AzNyDsGe9BnUVtHcaGR4ZHWU7nOOA1srST/tXKAiIgIioSVG2QjHRBTuxxa6w+ED/lKiFC1vAZyH/UfopaXWcutlY04A4EmT6tpUd6bRTxGfKK4bA1zGPZGeTgcNJz1HIkgfn1wGrBo7gAvNozkjJWzx6OqeXFq4o8lrWkxuIcXcMDB7xulAz+Eq9s2gZLla6OufcxTGpaTwX0pJYRuyD5w/ld3eHjyDTNo7hhfHBiJJMbCT3lq6BN2by0vAfPcd7HSMbI1sGzzS4NO1xJyefeFj5NGOfHSvpagtMn2geNw6OPmnAycN6deaDG6EYxutrEQxoIrosED8QUqlHzTWkZaDVlmnFQHCCaN8wLTzc0s3bOmW5d/hd8dUtDsAZ9eUFdFQbUBzg3b19aroC+XMa8YcMr6RBZXhoForuQ/88nylRFjcTG05PTxUur19z13u8nylREi+yZ/aEGStNvfcjXhk/C8joJq05bu38PB29RjOevPHgt00hBcG6bgraOuo2z8KbgU09M92WRTYe4vDwAc1JAG08sd/Na/oSmnray90tJE6aomsdWyONgyXOOwABbnpa31dDpinNbTvgFJDXw1Jk5cJ7qimLWu8CQCQgpX6xvvdRDR1F/o201E6RglgoH74pOO2nMZYZScFxb5xPRufFc1roH0VfVUkj976ad8JcOhLXFpI/JdrqbdUuuEsHkbRXyzSzFjI2te+Jtzjc15x1GwZye5ca1C4O1Fd3NIINfUEEd/8VyDI6DJdraxEkk+Wx9T61KbaPBRY0Bz1vYvfY/1UqEHmAvURAREQWV6+5q/3aT5SoiR/Zt9gUur59y1/u0nylRGYf4bfYEBzA4YcAR4ELo9tsVm+jVnqv+MikqKianime6m38ncLd38hhxO7uz0XOcqtHV1cTdsVVOxuMbWyuAx4Yz6h+SDZNfW+3UfksdDbY6dpfKJCKXZvc2RzMh248jtJDe4YOea1TGByVWWpqJY2xy1EsjGnLWPeSAfEAqkg2Ds+565sXvjFKdRZ7POeurF7439CpTICIiAiIgtbrC+otlXBEMySQPY0ZxklpAUe29k2sNgBoqbIHpTVI5EEcvql1f6HTfFNXv1Sav8ARKX4pqkYiCOf1Sav9Epfimp9Uer/AEWk+KH7KRiIOGaO7MtTWrVNruFbBStp6acSSFtQHHGD0GF3NEQEREH/2Q=="},{"imgURL":"data:image/jpeg;base64,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"}];





    function selBike(){
        var getVal = $('#bikes').val();


        if(getVal == "Allroad"){

            $('#demo').empty();

            var imgTag = $("<img src='"+ imgBikes[0].imgURL +"'></img>");

            $('#demo1').append(imgTag);
        }
        else{

            $('#demo').empty();

            var imgTag = $("<img src='"+ imgBikes[1].imgURL +"'></img>");

            $('#demo').append(imgTag);

        }

    }




    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Thus, you don't need store images your directory. Because image data is now encoded.
So, Don't care about my images...

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified bit of your code in order to make it as you expected.

### HTML:

- added 'this' reference to the 'selectBike' event call to access select control in event callback function.

### JS:

- by default image src is map to first index of given image reference array imgArray2.
- using 'this' reference which is passed as an argument we can access the selectedIndex and can change the src of the image accordingly.

```
var imgArray2 = ['KTM790', "KTM790D"];
    //by default
    document.querySelector("img").src = 'Bike/' + imgArray2[0];
    
    function selectBike(selectRef) { var x = document.getElementById('motor').value;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "you selected " + x;
      document.querySelector("img").src = 'Bike/' + imgArray2[selectRef.selectedIndex];
    }
    
    function selectWeather() { var c = document.getElementById('weather').value;
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "it's " + c;
    }
<select id="motor" onchange="selectBike(this)">
    <option value="Allroad">Allroad</option>
    <option value="Street">Street</option>
</select>

<div id="demo"></div>
<img src="" alt="">
```